# demo needs OpenCV for webcam images - unknown type name "namespace"

Tags: opencv, gcc, deep-learning, darknet

I'm using darknet yolo for machine learning. I already changed makefile YOLO OPENCV and tried to make:

```
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DOPENCV -c ./src/gemm.c -o obj/gemm.o
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h:48,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h:45,
                 from include/darknet.h:25,
                 from ./src/utils.h:5,
                 from ./src/gemm.c:2:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:485:1: error: unknown type name ‘namespace’
 namespace cv {
 ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
Makefile:85: recipe for target 'obj/gemm.o' failed
make: *** [obj/gemm.o] Error 1
```

It shows the above error. How to fix this?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? Looks like you're compiling some C code? What specific version of OpenCV?

Comment: I think you need the C++ compiler for `namespace`, try `g++-6` or `g++-7` instead of `gcc`